# R: Creating Axis "Breaks" in ggplot

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following data about how long patients stayed in the hospital (a date of 9999 means that they are still in the hospital, indicated by a triangle icon on the graph). Each patient can have multiple hospitalizations:

```
   var1 start_date   end_date
1     A 2019-09-30 2022-07-16
2     A 2019-11-17 2019-11-17
3     A 2019-02-06 2020-05-10
4     A 2014-06-11 2017-07-25
5     B 2013-07-15 2020-08-27
6     B 2021-03-06 2021-03-06
7     B 2018-01-17 2018-01-17
8     B 2016-02-17 2016-02-17
9     C 2022-03-26 2022-03-26
10    C 2016-06-07 2016-06-07
11    C 2016-06-22 2018-09-03
12    C 2015-11-05 2016-11-21
13    B 2023-01-01 9999-12-31

df = structure(list(var1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    start_date = structure(c(18169, 18217, 17933, 16232, 15901, 
    18692, 17548, 16848, 19077, 16959, 16974, 16744, 19358), class = "Date"), 
    end_date = structure(c(19189, 18217, 18392, 17372, 18501, 
    18692, 17548, 16848, 19077, 16959, 17777, 17126, 2932896), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I am trying to make the following graph which visualizes the length of each stay for each patient:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = start_date, xend = end_date, y = row, yend = row, color = hospital_patient)) +
  geom_segment(size = 1.5, lineend = "round") +
  geom_point(aes(x = start_date), size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$end_date != as.Date('2030-12-31'),], aes(x = end_date), size = 3) +
  geom_point(data = df[df$end_date == as.Date('2030-12-31'),], aes(x = end_date), size = 3, shape = 17) +
  scale_color_manual(values = palette) +
  labs(x = "Time", y = "Row") +
  theme_minimal()


p <- p + scale_x_date(labels = function(x) ifelse(format(x, "%Y") == '2030', '9999', format(x, "%Y")))


p <- p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept = as.numeric(Sys.Date()), linetype = "Today"), color = "black", size = 1.5)

p + scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Today" = "dotted"))
```

[image]

**My Question:** Currently, the only way I am able to visualize a patient that is still hospitalized is to manually replace all 9999 dates with some date in the future (e.g. 2030), and then replace this position on the x-axis with a date of 9999 - anything else results in the graph being distorted. Is it possible to do this with an "Axis break"? Also, I am not able to combine both legends (i.e. patient and today's date line) into a single legend - can this also be done?

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

*Note: updated after the OP posted newer example data*

What you have is a typical case of censoring: you don't know when the patient will be discharged, but you do know that at a certain date (e.g. today) it was still in the hospital.

Since there is no point in plotting hospital stays further than today, my approach would be to tag censored `end_date`s on a different variable, indicating whether or not the patient was discharged, and impute `Sys.Date()` on the "missing" `end_date`s.

```r
df$discharged <- df$end_date != as.Date("9999-12-31")
df$end_date[!df$discharged] <- Sys.Date()

# This was missing from the example data but is needed
# to replicate your plot
df$row <- 1:nrow(df)
```

You can then use the `discharged` column to define the shape of the points.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = start_date, xend = end_date, y = row, yend = row, color = var1)) +
geom_vline(xintercept = Sys.Date(), linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey50") +
geom_segment(linewidth = 1.5) +
geom_point(aes(x = start_date), size = 3) +
geom_point(aes(x = end_date, shape = discharged), size = 3) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 16)) +
labs(x = "Time", y = "Row") +
theme_minimal()
```

[image]

##### Alternative

Another visualization option would be to create a second "end" date for the `!discharged` patients, some time in the future (`Sys.Date() + 180`):

```r
# Column must be initialized as Date
df$end_date2 <- as.Date(NA)

df$end_date2[!df$discharged] <- Sys.Date() + 180
```

and then plot a solid line from `start_date` to `end_date` (imputed to today, as above), and then a dotted line from today to this second end date, as a sort of an ellipsis.  This way the lines for the patients still in the hospital would be solid from `start_date` to today, and then dotted from today to some days into the future.

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = start_date, xend = end_date, y = row, yend = row, color = var1)) +
geom_vline(xintercept = Sys.Date(), linetype = "dashed", colour = "grey50") +
geom_segment(linewidth = 1.5) +
geom_segment(aes(xend = end_date2), linetype = "11", linewidth = 1.5, alpha = 0.5) +
geom_point(aes(x = start_date), size = 3) +
geom_point(data = \(x) subset(x, discharged), aes(x = end_date), size = 3) +
scale_shape_manual(values = c(17, 16)) +
labs(x = "Time", y = "Row") +
theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! Sorry, I just realized there was no 9999 - please see the update. thank you so much!